# how to output result of subprocess.Popen process execution in realtime instead of it executing and then having the data available to display?

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, psutil

I wrote this first python script to help myself download songs, but when subprocess.Popen runs `youtube-dl.exe` to download song  it does not output in realtime, what I see is result once the youtube-dl.exe is done then the for loop iterates over each line and then does the check if the line has 100 in it.#

```
import win32clipboard
from urlparse import urlparse
import subprocess
import os
from os.path import expanduser

HOME = expanduser("~")
MUSIC_FOLDER = os.path.join(HOME, "Music")


def main():
    win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
    try:
        data = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData()
    except TypeError:
        print "Nothing in clipboard."
        return

    win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()

    o = urlparse(data)
    if o.scheme == "" and o.netloc == "":
        print "Invalid URL {0} in clipboard.".format(data)
        return
    url = o.geturl().replace(o.query, "").split("?")[0]
    os.chdir(MUSIC_FOLDER)
    youtube_dl = os.path.join(HOME, "wbin", "youtube-dl.exe")

    cmd = [youtube_dl, "-f", "140", url]
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    result = proc.communicate()[0]
    for output in result.split("\n"):
    print output
    if "100" in output:
            print "Your song is downloaded to {0}".format(MUSIC_FOLDER)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

how can I get output of for loop in terminal at the same time from the subprocess instead of subprocess.Popen compelting and then displaying or using the data output of `youtube-dl.exe` command.

Comment: If you want streaming output, you can't use `proc.communicate()`, as that's not going to return anything until the subprocess has finished.  Instead, you need to read small chunks of data from `proc.stdout`, and update your display with them.  You'll probably want to add `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` to the `Popen()` call, so that you don't risk a deadlock due to the process writing more than a bufferfull of data to stderr.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following implementation to get the `STDOUT` of shell script in real-time.

**Code:**

```
import subprocess

cmd = "ls"
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=1)
for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, ""):
    print(line.strip())
p.stdout.close()
p.wait()
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python test.py
README.md
__init__.py
__pycache__
admin
configs
database
```

Comment: I have already tried this, but it doesnt seems to be realtime.

Comment: It should be real-time. In your implementation the `proc.communicate()` waits the process to finishes and then returns the `STDOUT` and `STDERR`. In my example the `for` loop reads the `STDOUT` line-by-line while the process is running.